# Can a superuser log into a PostgreSQL server without a specific database assigned to them?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to log in to a PostgreSQL server. I do not know the inner workings of this server at the moment. But every time I do log in with the following commands:

```
psql postgres
psql -U username
```

I land up with this error:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "username", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Do I have to have a database assigned to me if I'm created as a super user on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are not specific to a database in PostgreSQL, but all databases in a cluster share the same users.

Still you need a database to connect to if you want to log into PostgreSQL – there cannot be a connection without a database. You also cannot switch databases while staying connected to the PostgreSQL server.

For administrative purposes PostgreSQL has the `postgres` database that you can use if you need a connection that is not to a specific database, e.g. if you just want to create a user or create or drop a database.

The statement you are looking for is

```
psql postgres username
```

If that fails, there is probably no entry in `pg_hba.conf` that allows `username` to log into `postgres` locally. Try with user `postgres`.

**Note:** Do not use PostgreSQL 8.4.

Comment: "You also cannot switch databases while staying connected to the PostgreSQL server" - you can switch between databases, psql uses \c for this. However access control is applied for this change.

Comment: @A.Scherbaum You don't stay connected when you use `\c`. `psql` disconnects and reconnects.